# Higher / lower game

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a higher / lower number game. So basically you get one number and the start and then you click a button - higher or lower. So if you click higher and the next number is higher you win otherwise you lose , same goes for lower.The problem comes when I click some of the buttons it gives a new number. So how can I prevent this? Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Gamble </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php

include('config.php');
if(!$_SESSION['username']) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

Menu();
isOnline();

$number = rand(0, 100);
echo $number;


if(isset($_POST['higher']) || isset($_POST['lower'])) {
    $num = $number;
    $newNumber = rand(0, 100);
    if($_POST['higher']) {
        if($newNumber > $num) {
            echo 'You win!<br>'.$newNumber;
        }
    } 
}

?>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="Submit" name="higher" value="Higher">
        <input type="Submit" name="lower" value="Lower">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

*Note: I know the lower button does not work , I just want to make it for higher 'cause it will work on the same way with lower..

EDIT:
Working version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Gamble </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <?php

    include('config.php');
    if(!$_SESSION['username']) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    Menu();
    isOnline();

    $num1 = rand(1, 100);

    if(isset($_POST)) {
        if($_POST['higher']) {
            $num2 = rand(1, 100);
            $oldNum = intval($_POST['num1']);
                if($num2 > $oldNum) {
                    echo "You win! Your number:".$oldNum." , and the new number is: ".$num2;
                }
        }
    }

    ?>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="Hidden" value="<?= $num1 ?>" name="num1"><?= $num1 ?><br>
        <input type="Submit" name="higher" value="Higher">
        <input type="Submit" name="lower" value="Lower">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Store the generated number in a session when it's not set.

Comment: You need to store the random generated number in the session and not create a new one until the game is over.

Comment: Okay I'll try to do it with a session. Thanks guys :)

Comment: This doesn't relate to the problem, but FYI, calls to `header()` must appear before any unbuffered output. This means that it should be the first thing in the file before the `<!DOCTYPE ...` See http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: Actually managed to do it without header() and sessions.. I updated my question.

Comment: @tsvmitev You can do it that way, only thing here is that an user can see the number in the source code

Comment: Yep it's exploitable i'm trying to prevent it ;/